# Import Sharepoint XML based requirements to HP Quality Center

Tags: sharepoint, hp-quality-center

We're thinking of moving away from Sharepoint 2003 and to HP Quality Center for our requirements tracking system. Is there a way to import our current Sharepoint requirements and user stories to HP Quality Center?

Has anyone had any issues/successes with HP Quality Center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are add-ins for importing requirements from Word or Excel to QC or you can also use QC's OTA API to create custom scripts for importing data from Sharepoint to QC.